# How to filter within another array filter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript

I have below json data.

I want to ignore records which having status "Pending"? I tried with below code but it returning all records Empid 101 and 102.

```
 var res = emp.filter(
      e =>
        e.statuses.filter(
          s =>
            s.status !== "complete"
        )
    );

console.log(res);
```

**expected output: empId 102**

```
  [{
        "empId": "101",
        "statuses": [{
                "status": "pending",
                "order": 1
            },
            {
                "status": "complete",
                "order": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "empId": "102",
        "statuses": [{
                "status": "inprogress",
                "order": 1
            },
            {
                "status": "complete",
                "order": 2
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

Comment: Your data structure is not valid and also does not match your code at the moment. `emp` is an object, but has duplicate keys, but you're iterating over it as if it was an array with `.filter`? Can you fix it?

Comment: `emp.filter(e => e.statuses.filter(s => s.status === 'completed').length === e.statuses.length);`

Comment: You json data is not correct. It should be probably like this 
`var emp=[
    {
        "empId":"101",
       "statuses":[
         {
            "status":"pending",
            "order":1
         },
         {
            "status":"complete",
            "order":2
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      "empId":"102",
       "statuses":[
         {
            "status":"complete",
            "order":1
         },
         {
            "status":"complete",
            "order":2
         }
      ] 
    }  
]`

Comment: corrected valid json

Answer (score 0):

Use the every function to make sure all the statuses are complete.

```
const emps = [{
        "empId": "101",
        "statuses": [{
                "status": "pending",
                "order": 1
            },
            {
                "status": "complete",
                "order": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "empId": "102",
        "statuses": [{
                "status": "complete",
                "order": 1
            },
            {
                "status": "complete",
                "order": 2
            }
        ]
    }

]

var res = emps.filter(emp => emp.statuses.every(status => status.status !== "pending"))

console.log(res);
```

Result:

```
[{
    empId: "102",
    statuses: [{
        order: 1,
        status: "complete"
    }, {
        order: 2,
        status: "complete"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: ignore EmpId 101 from result

Comment: changed JSON data, If status having as inprogress then every() function not returning expected result  . What should be the right function to use?

Comment: So you want to remove pending but keep anything else?

Comment: You can still use `every`, just change to `status !== "pending"`